# Django Queryset: filter by weeks

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter a query by weeks.  It will return jobs if the jobs report_by_date is within a week.

```
Job.objects.filter((report_by_date-datetime.today()).days <= 7)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create a datetime for one week ago, then filter all jobs after that.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
one_week_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)
jobs = Job.objects.filter(report_by_date__gte=one_week_ago)
```

Answer (score 14):

Since django 1.11, you can do:

```
Jobs.objects.filter(report_by_date__week=52)
```

It will give you the week from monday to sunday, according to ISO-8601.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#week